# How do I highlight and use the highlighted line in a text box?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, variables, textbox, highlight

I am trying to make a machine code emulator. It is to run through each line/instruction and doing certain functions depending on the the curtain line indicated by highlight.

How would I highlight a line in a text box and be able to use it as a string or int automatically with the program not manually.

I have a IO class that reads in the text from a text file. In my text file the text looks like this

```
00 0000000
01 0000000
02 0000000
03 0000000
```

When I have my IO class reads it in, in the method it returns a string S.

My S is one whole string " 00 0000000 \n 01 0002020 \n 02 0020202 \n 03 0101001" but when
it is displayed in the textbox it appears as below.

For example in my textbox I have

```
00 0000000
01 0000000
02 0000000
03 0000000
```

My program will start at line 0 and as it goes through each line, it will automatically highlight the line it is on to indicate which line/instruction the program is on.

How would I highlight a specific line so my program lets the user know that line is being used.

For example the program is on line 3.

```
02 0000000
```

It would highlight that and display that line 3 is being used in the text box.

How would I be able to use each line as a separate line or integer. Since the string was original a single string with just new lines added in. How would I be able to separate each line in the text box as its own string or integer to be used for computing.

For example, Let say the program is on line 3 It would highlight line 3.

```
02 0000000
```

Then lets add 1 to it.

```
int N=1, sum=0;
sum = line3 +N;
```

then display the result back in a specific line or the curtain line in the textbox.

I have to be able to rewrite it back to the textfile the same way it is appeared in the textbox.
So if line 3 change, the textfile should look like this

```
00 0000000
01 0000000
02 0000001  // or just 1
03 0000000
```

Comment: what effort have you made? what ui framework?

Comment: `Dragael` you can start by doing a simple google search there literally hundreds of examples out there on the internet

Comment: @Daniel A. White, I have a lot so far. I have a memory txtBox that read in the values and add a new line for each line from a text file. I'm trying to make it read a line and be able to use the line as a int or string to display it and do some computing in another textbox.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I searched which is why, I have no answer. All of them are either a richtextBox or not what i'm looking for. I'm trying to make a a Emulator of a virtual Machine code machine.

Comment: so did you so a google search on the following 
[c# highlight text in richtextbox](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23 highlight text in richtextbox) I find it hard to believe that you can't find anything

Comment: @DJKRAZE That is richtextbox, I'm trying to do this on a regular textbox. Which is why I looked around and all I found is richtextbox or listbox nothing about regular textbox highlight. I'm trying to code a program that automatic highlight the section for you to indicate what line you are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How do I highlight a line in a text box and be able to use it as a
>   string or int?
>  ...
>  How would I highlight a specific line
>   so my program lets the user know that line is being used.*

By using a mouse : hold left button where the selection should start, move to the desired position in your textbox, then release mouse button.

*If this wasn't the answer you were looking for*, what I can do for you right now is to inform you that a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` has the following Properties :

- `.SelectionStart` where a selection start, but also where the key input ***is***.
- `.SelectionLength` which is the length of the selection in number of chars. If it is `0`, that means there is no selected text.

Now, without knowing what's the logic/conditions to select - programmaticaly - some lambda numeric chars, ***you can't ask us to guess***. And it's normal google returns garbage, because google don't understand want you want to do. Which kind of selection is correct ?

- 00 0000000
  01 0002020
  **02** 0020202
  03 0101001
- 00 0000000
  01 0002020
  **02 0020202**
  03 0101001
- 00 0000000
  01 0002020
  02 **0020202**
  03 0101001
- 00 0000000
  01 0002020
  02 0**0202**02
  03 0101001

Why line 2 but not line 0 or line 45 ? How are we supposed to know where to start a selection an where to end it ? (Note, Line indexes are base-0, ie, human-line1 is computer-line0, human-line2 is computer-line1... The same goes for character index : first character is indexed [0])

---

> *How would I be able to use that line as a int or a string.*

```
TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.SelectionStart, TextBox1.SelectionLength) => String
```

> *as an int*

```
int MyInt = 0;
if (Int.TryParse(MySelection, MyInt))
{
    // ... you can use MyInt...
}
```

Carefull : If you have whitespaces or linebreaks, you must remove those (visible or invisible) chars to have a concatenated integer expressed as string. But again, the logic depends on your goal. We can't guess if spaces and linebreaks are considered as number separators or ignore them (delete them in that case)

---

> *So I can have it as a a string or int variable, to put in a different text box.*

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.SelectionStart, TextBox1.SelectionLength)
```

---

You should divide your problem in smaller ones, but believe me, just right here, you have answers to those *smaller* problems. How to convert a string to integer C# ? How to remove spaces in string C# ? How to remove linebreaks in string C# ? ...

Read the documentation of [.SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [.SelectionLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You said RichTextBox is not what you're looking for.. RichTextBox derives from TextBoxBase aswell as TextBox.

Fact is, if you don't try, or at least explain your goals in details, don't expect someone to help. It's like if I'm asking you [how do I use a hammer ?](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?642231-RESOLVED-namespace-folders-deployment&s=7184cc561b2beb1de80f4b933693d46f&p=3967362&viewfull=1#post3967362) Don't worry. I didn't downvote... But I may (and I should) at a later time is no more *efforts from you* in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for writing back in such detail, I appreciate it!
I am trying to write a Machine code emulator, I would like the program to automatically highlight the line that is certainly being used as the instruction for the machine code.

 As for line two, I just selected it at random for example. So if my program is doing the machine code on line two, it will high light line two. The entire thing so 02 0000000 will be highlighted. The program will start at Line 0 and it will move on to next line unless a instruction changes it to a different line.

Comment: I have a class that reads in the text from a text file each line in the text file I addead a Enviroment.NewLine to make sure the new line displays in the textbox.
Then I set the textbox to equal the string that was returned from the the class method I used to read in the file. So my textbox I believe is just one whole string right now but with new lines between each line in the text file. I'm not sure how to select each individual line in the textbox when the text box was one single string to begin with. For example my string is "00 000000 \n 01 000000 \n 02 0000000"

Comment: In my Text box it wouldn't appear as one line it would appear as 3 separate lines. I'm trying to figure how I can have a text box that would let me select either line 0, line 1 or line 2, and be able to use that line as a integer or a string so I can do some computing with it. For example, if I select line 2 I would get " 02 0000000" and set it equal to string  S, and I have a integer N = 4, and sum =0; I would like do sum = N + S.ConvertToInt32().

Comment: I'm unsure how I can separate each line as a separate string and use them individually. I also need to write them back to a text file in the same format where each line/instruction is its own line. Sorry if my English is crap and my grammar sucks. Not sure if I answered everything. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Dragael - What you're asking is *too broad*; reason why it's _put on hold_ is relevant. The easiest control to use for what you want to achieve is a ListBox. Not that a TextBox can't do the job, but managing its userinterface (updating the selection) *would require a huge amount of code*. That's the analogy I meant by _How do I use a hammer_. What you want to achieve seems far beyoud the scope of your question.

Comment: @Dragael - I suggest you use two tools instead of a `TextBox` : a `ListBox` and a `custom Class` that contains each line loaded from the File using `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` and link both tools in order for the class to know which _line_ is selected in the Listbox, and for the class to make the listbox select (and scroll to) an item. The class handles each line conversion to `integer` so you get the integer value of the selected line, deleting by the way any whitespace sneaking in.

Comment: @Dragael - However, yes, a TextBox (or a RichTextBox) is a nice tool, because you can write more text perfectly aligned next to the _numeric address_, just like in Visual Studio or Context or Notepad++ or SharpDevelop IDEs. No, you're not the first to write the source code of a code emulator or so, the UserInterface is the same even if the purpose is different. But NO, those tools aren't simple default dotNet controls. Their rendering to screen uses a massive amount of (managed and unmanaged) source code, not just a few lines you can write here on SO.

Comment: @Dragael - So, think again. A linebreak in a Textbox can take one, two or three chars, chars that you don't _really_ see on screen. Using `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` **MUST** take account of that. The `.Lines` property of the TextBox and `Environment.NewLine.Length` would nicely help, until you come up with another idea like multiple selections, scrolling control, or different background colors... Soon enough, you may think of dropping the usual controls (textbox/listbox) and rewrite everything using GDI+ (or WPF) Anyway, SO is not the place to ask _how to do that_ I'm sorry.

Comment: @Dragael - _Did you read the documentation I linked **to start with** ?_ Now your question is put on hold, it's even not possible to give more details. In my comments above, I honestly think I've given enough hints (in code format) to get you started with writing some bits of code. Copy/Paste those hints in google will get you on as many pages as you want that explain you how to use them... Do it ! I won't write the UserInterface code of your emulator and I highly doubt someone else (ever) will.

Comment: @Dragael - _"how I can have a text box that would let me select either line 0, line 1.."_ **You can't !** TextBox is Text, not Lines. To do that, you **must** do it programmatically with (some or many) lines of code.. _".. and I have a integer N = 4, and sum =0; I would like do sum = N + S.ConvertToInt32().."_ See : You want to use a hammer to drive screws `:/` _"I also need to write them back to a text file in the same format .."_ That's outside the scope of line selection in textbox... Sorry. That's too much for today :/ Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I realized mine was too board, I tried to simplify this massive thing into a short thing to make it sound easy but it made me realize its too board and complicated. I took your advice and did a listbox instead of a regular textbox. I have finished the code. Thanks!